How can I run Chrome headful on headless Ubuntu Server?
So I have this Node.js application which uses Puppeteer (alternative for eg, Selenium) which is a browser bot/web driver. For my specific use-case, I need to run Chrome headful, but I just cannot get it to work.
I have barely any Linux knowledge. I do have decent terminal knowledge because I'm on MacOS, but that's how far it goes.
The reason I want headless Ubuntu Server is to save RAM, because I really don't need a GUI for anything. Is it even possible to do what I'm trying to achieve?
So far I've tried using `Xvfb` but Chrome just gives me a bunch of errors:
root@x:~# Xvfb -ac :99 -screen 0 1280x1024x16 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
[1] 3204
root@x:~# DISPLAY=:99.0 chromium --no-sandbox
[3207:3284:0503/123414.921007:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(576)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.ListActivatableNames: object_path= /org/freedesktop/DBus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.5" (uid=0 pid=3207 comm="/snap/chromium/2842/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrom" label="snap.chromium.chromium (enforce)") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus" member="ListActivatableNames" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.DBus" (bus)
[3207:3207:0503/123415.185094:ERROR:chrome_browser_cloud_management_controller.cc(161)] Cloud management controller initialization aborted as CBCM is not enabled. Please use the `--enable-chrome-browser-cloud-management` command line flag to enable it if you are not using the official Google Chrome build.
[3207:3284:0503/123415.446231:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(576)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.ListActivatableNames: object_path= /org/freedesktop/DBus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.7" (uid=0 pid=3207 comm="/snap/chromium/2842/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrom" label="snap.chromium.chromium (enforce)") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus" member="ListActivatableNames" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.DBus" (bus)
[3306:3306:0503/123415.812393:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(302)] No suitable EGL configs found.
[3306:3306:0503/123415.814730:ERROR:gl_context_egl.cc(160)] eglGetConfigAttrib failed with error EGL_BAD_CONFIG
libva error: /snap/chromium/2842/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/virtio_gpu_drv_video.so init failed
[3306:3306:0503/123415.889614:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(302)] No suitable EGL configs found.
[3306:3306:0503/123415.889924:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1040)] eglCreatePbufferSurface failed with error EGL_BAD_CONFIG
[3306:3306:0503/123415.893292:ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(86)] gl::GLContext::CreateOffscreenGLSurface failed
[3306:3306:0503/123415.893950:ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(582)] Could not create surface for info collection.
[3306:3306:0503/123415.894861:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(103)] CollectGraphicsInfo failed.
[3306:3306:0503/123415.919347:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(198)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
(chrome:3207): IBUS-WARNING **: 12:34:16.415: Failed to mkdir /root/snap/chromium/2842/.config/ibus/bus: Not a directory
[3207:3358:0503/123416.661211:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(576)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get: object_path= /org/freedesktop/UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files
[3207:3358:0503/123416.661747:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(576)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.UPower.GetDisplayDevice: object_path= /org/freedesktop/UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files
[3207:3358:0503/123416.662276:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(576)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.UPower.EnumerateDevices: object_path= /org/freedesktop/UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files
[3356:3356:0503/123417.103803:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(302)] No suitable EGL configs found.
[3356:3356:0503/123417.104363:ERROR:gl_context_egl.cc(160)] eglGetConfigAttrib failed with error EGL_BAD_CONFIG
libva error: /snap/chromium/2842/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/virtio_gpu_drv_video.so init failed
[3356:3356:0503/123417.110956:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(302)] No suitable EGL configs found.
[3356:3356:0503/123417.111222:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1040)] eglCreatePbufferSurface failed with error EGL_BAD_CONFIG
[3356:3356:0503/123417.111440:ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(86)] gl::GLContext::CreateOffscreenGLSurface failed
[3356:3356:0503/123417.111605:ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(582)] Could not create surface for info collection.
[3356:3356:0503/123417.111767:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(103)] CollectGraphicsInfo failed.
[3356:3356:0503/123417.138033:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(198)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
libva error: /snap/chromium/2842/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/virtio_gpu_drv_video.so init failed
[3339:3353:0503/123417.516431:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(131)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuControl.CreateCommandBuffer.

I have no clue about what's going on or how to even get started to fix any of these 
Hoping someone could help me out here, would be greatly appreciated!

"For my specific use-case, I need to run Chrome headful" -- what makes you think this? "The reason I want headless Ubuntu Server..." -- I thought you wanted a headful Ubuntu server? "I really don't need a GUI for anything" -- then why not run headlessly?

I need Chrome headful because I need to be able to run Chrome extensions which requires headful (enforced by Puppeteer) & do video + audio recording. I don't need a full-fledged GUI, I just need to be able to render Chrome.

Thanks. I would [edit] your post to clarify and remove the contradiction.

Fixed the issue. Basically a combination of https://github.com/mujo-code/puppeteer-headful/blob/master/Dockerfile and a bit of trial and error, I got it up and running.
Quick overview:

Install correct dependencies by installing google-chrome-stable (see link)
Pass the new chrome as executable to puppeteer using execPath
Use Xvfb to host a display server
Pass the port & screen to puppeteer using env.DISPLAY
Add flag args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox", "--disable-gpu"]

No GUI, no WM, no Compositor setup or anything. Works straight on Ubuntu Server.
